# swimlane / ngx-datatable: how to detect if a row on click is expand or not?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

If you click on a line, it expands and the details can be seen. This apparently happens with the "toggle". But how can I now determine whether a line has already been expanded?

HTML

```
 <ngx-datatable
   #dataTable
   ...
   (select)='onRowSelect($event)'
   (activate)="onLoadDataDetails($event)">
```

TS

```
  onRowSelect(row: any): void {
    if (row && row.selected) {
      this.dataTable.rowDetail.toggleExpandRow(row.selected[0]);
    }
  }

  onLoadDataDetails(row: any): void {
    if (row.type === 'click') {
      this.loadDetails(row.row.id);
    }
  }
```

otherwise the request (this.loadDetails) is triggered when opening and closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem on add a methode to set an internal variable.

```
<ngx-datatable-row-detail
 #myDetailRow>
  <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
    <div *ngIf="expanded?setExpandStatus(expanded):false"></div>
```

component:

```
  setExpandStatus(expanded: any): void {
    this.rowIsNotExpanded = expanded;
  }

  onLoadDataDetails(row: any): void {
    if (row.type === 'click') {
      if (!this.rowIsNotExpanded) {
        this.loadDetails(row.row.id);
      }
    }
  }
```